# adding dynamic content to _Layout.vbhtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

So moving over to MVC finally from web forms

so within my main _Layout.vbhtml I have a menu as follows:

```
                        <a href="#" class="has-arrow"><i class="material-icons">person</i> Account</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="account-signin.aspx">Sign In / Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="account-profile.aspx">Profile Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="account-orders.aspx">Orders List</a></li>
                            <li><a href="account-order-detail.aspx">Order Detail</a></li>
                            <li><a href="account-wishlist.aspx" class="has-badge">Wishlist <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">3</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="account-address.aspx">Address</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

I want this to now come from the DB dynamically

in the web forms world this would have been a master page, I would have then added a literal and then populated it on the page load in the code behind.

But how do I archive the same now in MVC

Comment: Lots of examples out there like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bind-menu-and-sub-menu-dynamically-in-mvc-from-database-using-linq/).

Comment: seems a MASSIVE overhead to create another view and then add the controller all to spit out a few lines of html from the DB :-( thought MVC was supposed to improve things, this makes it three times the amount of code it would have been in web forms...

Comment: I said the same thing about COBOL :) That is just vanilla MVC. There are more advanced solutions like [sitemaps](https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2014/10/03/asp-net-mvc-5-menu-using-site-map-provider-bootstrap-3-navbar/) or javascript libraries (we use Kendo).

Answer (score 0):

ended up doing this in _layout.html, works but unsure if its the correct way :-)

@Code
    Dim listGroups As List(Of ProductGroups) = ProductGroups.MenuList()
End Code

then further down the page:

```
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="has-arrow"><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i> Shop</a>
                        <ul>
                            @For Each item In listGroups
                                @<li><a href="@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.GroupURL)" title="@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Group)">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Group)</a></li>
                            Next
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

as I said does what i expect but not sure if that's how your 'supposed' to do it?